# Action When Button is Pressed Down Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: button, cocos2d-iphone

How would i trigger `- (void)onRightButtonClicked:(id)sender` when the button is **being** pressed, not when it has **been** pressed (let go).

This is the code for the button

```
rightButton = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@"" spriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"right.png"]];
rightButton.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width/3.65, self.contentSize.height/10);
[rightButton setTarget:self selector:@selector(onRightButtonClicked:)];
[self addChild:rightButton];
```

And then what happens after the button has been pressed.

```
- (void)onRightButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
CCActionAnimate *animationAction = [CCActionAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim];
CCActionRepeatForever *repeatingAnimation = [CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:animationAction];
[dino runAction:repeatingAnimation];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no 1-2 liner for that one, if you check `CCButton.m` you can see when actions are triggered

```
- (void) touchUpInside:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super setHitAreaExpansion:_originalHitAreaExpansion];

    if (self.enabled)
    {
        [self triggerAction];
    }

    self.highlighted = NO;
}
```

### Really dirty quickfix

If you want ALL buttons in your game to have this behaviour just move `[self triggerAction]` to `- (void) touchEntered:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`in `CCButton`.

### Elegant'ish solution

Make a custom subclass of `CCButton` where you override the `touchUpInside` and `touchEntered` methods. But since these are not public you would have to create a `CCButton_Protected.h` header where you import your normal `CCButton` header and put the private method signatures that you want to override in there.

Comment: I decided the do the dirty way because i wanted all the buttons to do this, thank you! :D

Comment: You are welcome. When you have the time I would suggest implementing the proper solution, mainly because it will cause you problems when you want to update Cocos. You would have to reimplement these changes if you want to keep using the "dirty" solution.

Comment: I have another question, how would i make it so that the action will only happen while the button is pressed?

Comment: Override touchEntered to trigger the action

Comment: I meant being pressed down, so the action would repeat while the button is being pressed then stop when the button has been released

Comment: @Crazycriss - make the question so someone can provide a useful answer, this way we all get the benefits of it.

Perhaps the "proper" solution is to add it as a cocos2d improvement...this topic has been around for ages now.

Comment: @Tibor Udvari : great answer !